# Special treatment to part of PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I want to add a special class to the a certain entry of an array value.  What do I need to add to that value in the array to give it's 'li' a special class?

I have an array like this:

```
"notes" => [
    "$100.00 Credit to Use at Any of",
    "the Domestic Bliss Spa Locations",
    "$100.00 Value",
    "Another list item",
    "yet another list item"
]
```

And I loop through these to spit out html like this:

```php
<?php foreach ($slide['notes'] as $note): ?>
    <li><?= $note; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I want the value `$100.00 Value` to have a special class.

Comment: What do you mean a "special class"? Why can't you just add the class you want to the `<li>` element? Do you mean a class with the item's `id` perhaps?

Comment: You need some sorts of identifier, if it's always on 2nd index or contains that exact value. then you just do if check inside foreach ``$note == '$100.00 Value``

Comment: @Bono because I don't want to add the class to every list item.  Only to certain values.  So i wouldn't want a class on all the list items, just a class "special" on the list item containing "$100.00 Value"

Comment: Simply add an if function to recognize if the value contains `$100.00` so add the special class to your HTML `<li class="special_class">$100.00 Value</li>` code..!

Comment: So many ways to do this (and most of them are terrible, so use the first): Use objects instead of simple strings to add additional info (like additional css classes), put a *special* character at the end of the string and check for that in php, test for this specific value with an `if($note == "$100.00 Value")`, etc.

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai See my comment to the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php foreach ($slide['notes'] as $note): ?>
    <li <?php if ($note == "$100.00 Value") echo "class='specialClass'" ?>><?= $note; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you.  That would definitely work, but there are many, many instances of the "notes" array and I need this special class on many other values.  Could I somehow nest an array under any value that needs this class and then set an conditional like "if the value has a nested array?" Not sure if that would be a good resolution.

Comment: Yeah, a workaround can be something like that or you can put a comma on the end of the $note that needs the special class and inside the iff you echo the class and remove the comma if needed.

Comment: There must be something in common with the values you wanna apply the class on. Use that as a identifier for the if statement and you're done.

Comment: @JordanBarber if my answer helped you, please accept it as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check for multiple values like this way as :

```
<?php 
foreach ($slide['notes'] as $note) {
$values = array("$300.00", "$200.00", "$100.00", "$55.00");
if (in_array($note, $values))
{
echo  "<li class='special_class_name'>$note</li>";
} else {
    echo  "<li>$note</li>";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check if `$note` contains `$100.00 Value` and use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($slide['notes'] as $note){
echo (strpos($note, '$100.00 Value') !== false) ? "<li class='someClass'>{$note}</li>" : "<li>{$note}</li>";
}
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/WML4Fs)